# How to sum individual values in Excel based on changes in other column

Tags: excel

I want to create a formula in Excel that sums values based on values in another column. The second column is based on an `IF` function:

```
=IF(K4>=$N$1,0,IF(K3<$N$1,0,1)).
```

Every time a set of "1" occurs, it is grouped as a single event. But now I want to sum the values that are based on this grouping. So the first set of "1" should give a total of 4 and the second set of "1" should give 5.

Is there a way to let Excel sum the first column every time the second column changes from 0 to 1, knowing that the sets of "1" in the first column is different every time?

```
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   1
0   0
0   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this that sums the first column to that point and subtracts the current column total to that point:

```
=IF(A2>A3,SUM($A$2:A2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

[image]